# Is it possible (and a good idea) to do `pw lock root` on FreeBSD?

Tags: security, freebsd, password, root

I have set up `sudo` on my FreeBSD server. As I now never want to log in as root anymore, I was wondering whether I should do `sudo pw lock root`.

My questions are:

- Is this possible, without forever disabling my machine?
- Is it a smart idea, or is there a good reason to not do this?
- Will I still be able to do `sudo su` to get a root shell?

Comment: This is actually the default configuration for Ubuntu: root account is locked, and sudo prompts for your own password.  Running sudo to run su as root to run a shell as root is also redundant; just use sudo -s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually did this on my FreeBSD box - so yes, it is possible, but of course you should take care to verify that `sudo` works properly before you do so ;-)

`sudo su` will not work anymore, but you can still do `sudo bash` to get a root shell.

Comment: or sudo -s will also get you a shell

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, yes.

But it's not a very good idea. Locking out the account is equivalent to setting an absolutely unguessable password. You might as well set a practically unguessable password, i.e. one with sufficient entropy (128 bits, which comes out to 20 random printable ASCII characters, is massive overkill), and keep that password in a safe.